# How do I create NFS exports on virtualised NetApp from CLI?

Tags: nfs, netapp

How do I list the NFS exports from clustered NepApp from command line?

While I was able to create volumes and to configure an export policy I am unable to find which are the exports that
I should be able to mount on my machines.

```
lcy2-dosvm01::vserver export-policy rule> show
Policy Rule Access Client RO
Vserver Name Index Protocol Match Rule
------------ --------------- ------ -------- --------------------- ---------
lcy2-dosvm01 cache 1 any 10.71.0.0/16 any

lcy2-dosvm01::> volume show
Vserver   Volume       Aggregate    State      Type       Size  Available Used%
--------- ------------ ------------ ---------- ---- ---------- ---------- -----
lcy2-dosvm01
          backup       do_aggr0_filer01a
                                    online     RW          1TB    972.8GB    5%
                                    online     RW         22TB    20.90TB    5%
lcy2-dosvm01
          cache        do_aggr0_filer01a
                                    online     RW          6TB     5.70TB    5%
```

I also created the junction paths:

```
vserver mount -volume cache -junction-path /cache


lcy2-dosvm01::> volume show -volume cache -junction
                                Junction                            Junction
Vserver   Volume       Language Active    Junction Path             Path Source
--------- ------------ -------- --------  ------------------------- -----------
lcy2-dosvm01
          cache        C.UTF-8  true      /cache                    RW_volume
```

On the client:

```
+ showmount -e filer48
Export list for filer48:
/ (everyone)
```

... and obviously any mount command seems to fail with access denied message, even if the client IP is inside the specified policy.

Answer (score 1):

An export policy is just a container for export rules. Create a rule with [vserver export-policy rule create](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1366832/html/vserver/export-policy/rule/create.html) to actually assign a host access to a share.

If you want to see what the effective permissions are, you can use [vserver export-policy check-access](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1610202/html/vserver/export-policy/check-access.html). To list the effective permissions, [you would use vserver export-policy rule show](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1610202/html/vserver/export-policy/rule/show.html).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the export policy you created is assigned to the volumes in question.

```
vol show -fields policy,junction-path
```

Also make sure the client has at least read access to the vserver's root volume. You can just use the same export policy as the data volume if that makes it easier.